# How to print OpenCv matrix depending on data type in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I need to print an OpenCV matrix of which I don't know the type before. Since I'm iterating through all entries in a loop using the .at function I need a mapping from the matrix type to the C++ data type. However I don't want to check for every case (CV_8UC1 ... CV_64FC4).

Can I just convert the matrix into a known data type like or  and just read the matrix using myMatrix.at for example?

Here is the code:

```
fstream << vecMat[0].rows<<" "<<vecMat[0].cols<<" "<<vecMat.size()<<" \n";
// Print 3d matrix as a 2d matrix
for(int x=0; x < vecMat[0].rows; x++)
{
    for(int z=0; z < vecMat.size(); z++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < vecMat[0].cols; y++)
        {
                fstream << vecMat[z].at<UNKNOWN_DATA_TYPE>(x,y)<<" ";
        }
    }
    fstream<<" \n";
}
```

Edit:
format(R,"csv" ) is not helping because I need the matrix fields to be separated by space not by comma. That makes it easier for me to read the matrix in using for example

```
fstream >> vecMat[z].at<double>(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` is overloaded natively for the `mat` type, and you can specify its format to change its appearance. For example (where `R` is any`mat`):

`cout << "R (numpy)   = " << endl << format(R,"numpy" ) << endl << endl;`

A full list of these formats are available [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#output-formatting).

Comment: I already knew those formats. Unfortunately I need the output similar to format(R,"csv"   ) but only with "space" instead of "comma" as field delimiter. That makes it easier for me to read the matrix in afterwards using fstream >> myInt. I will detail my question